# Missing { inserted. in equation latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols, overleaf, math-operators

I'm writing a latex equation,

```
\begin{equation}
    X^"=\frac{X^'}{\norm{X}^2} (l_2 Normalization)
\end{equation}
```

and getting errors,

```
Missing { inserted.‪
```

You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.

Use $...$ for inline math mode, and [...]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).
i cant figure out where is the missing bracket.

Comment: Your code cannot be used to show the error: it's missing at least `\documentclass` and the `document` environment, the `\norm` macro is undefined, and if I replace it with something simple like `\text` then it compiles with no error. As usual here, provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Also, why use `X^"` and `X^'`? `"` and `'` are already superscripted.

Comment: Without to see an MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document), which reproduce your problem, we also can't see the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guessing that possible MWE with your equation can be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,
            mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{\ifblank{#1}{{\cdot}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
X''=\frac{X'}{\norm{X}^2}\qquad (l_2 \text{ Normalization})
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

however, your definition of `\norm` is unknown, alo are unknown used packages and `\documentclass` ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
    X''=\frac{X'}{\| X^2 \|} \quad (l_2 \, \textrm{Normalization})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As per Miyase's comment to the question this is not a good answer. At least fix the `^'`'s

Comment: I focused on the problem with the { } and forgot to fix the X^"

Comment: `\mathrm{Normalization}` never use math italic for words