# list of figures content goes beyond the page width latex

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, packages, page-breaking, texstudio

I have a problem with latex list of figures content going beyond the page content width. the sample is shown below figure, please let me know any solution.

[image]

Comment: You need to enable a line break at the desired positions. I don't know what your code looks like, but you probably want to line break like `(a)~S2VT\-/CNN\-/Attention+\allowbreak{}LSTM` (Here I am using the `extdash` package shortcuts.)

Comment: Please, always show a minimal working example with all the code needed to reproduce the issue and without the need to change anything to reproduce the issue. Currently we even do not know the class and how you've coded the caption text. See also the comments to [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664513).

Comment: I wonder if the URL package would help?

Comment: full code related to this post,
%% List of figures 
\let\origaddvspace\addvspace
\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures